# How to add space after and before curly braces?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am doing Flutter development and when I save, the code get formatted. It is nice but some settings are not what I want. For example, I would like to add a space after and before curly brace for my constructor:

Before

```
Device({this.deviceType});
```

After

```
Device({ this.deviceType });
```

How can I adjust Dart formatting or VS Code to handle that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure `dartfmt`, the Dart formatter, to do this as it's intended to make *all* Dart code look the same regardless of the author. See the [FAQ of package:dart_style](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ) (the backend of `dartfmt`) for more information as to why the formatter isn't configurable.

Comment: Yeah, you can't, because dartfmt is formatting according to the style guide, and Google wants code checkins to not introduce extra newlines.

Answer (score 0):

The Dart formatter respects linter style rules as laid out in the "analysis_options.yaml" file. A description of the file can be found [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options). A complete list of linter rules can be found [here](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/).

You can also subscribe to common style guides, such as [pedantic](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic), a package with the style guide used internally by Google, or [lint](https://pub.dev/packages/lint), another package that enables all the rules that aren't either contradictory or opinionated.

Comment: I don't think that `dartfmt` actually does anything with `analysis_options.yaml`. As far as I know, that's only ever read by `dartanalyzer`.